# ImportError: cannot import name 'cast' from partially initialized module 'keras.src.backend'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tr

I have imported the following libraries for my machine learning project but have problem when I try to run my model in the terminal:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
```

and an error message appears:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'cast' from partially initialized module 'keras.src.backend' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\__init__.py)
```

Hope someone can help me resolve this error?

Comment: Python version? Tensorflow version? OS?

Comment: My Tensorflow and keras are both on version 2.15.0

Comment: and I use python version 3.11.6

Comment: I had this problem with "tensorflow==2.15.0.post1" and "keras==2.15.0". Then I installed "tensorflow==2.15.0" and "keras==2.15.0" that solved the problem. I also tested with "tensorflow==2.8.0" and "keras==2.8.0" and that also works.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling and installing keras fixed it for me. I uninstalled keras with:

```
pip uninstall keras
```

Then I installed a keras version compatible with my tensorflow version - [version compatibility can be found here.](https://keras.io/getting_started/#tensorflow-compatibility) In my case, I had tensorflow version 2.14.0, so I installed keras version 2.14.0 with:

```
pip install keras==2.14.0
```